# Current Directory of a VB.net Windows Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, service

For some reason the Current Directory of my windows service is C:\Windows\System32
and when I schedule my service I get this error Access is Denied.

In one of the blogs I saw this peice to change the current directory.
But I am not sure where to place this code.

Thanks

```
 System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
```

Comment: Windows Vista/Seven? And, please elaborate and clear up the question a little, it helps getting more answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how your program depends[sic] on the current directory, but I'm sure where you need it is early in your service start up function, which would be `OnStart(string[] args)` in your service class that inherits from `ServiceBase`.
Windows Services are initialized with CD set to what's specified on the service's settings.